# You took cold juice out of a fridge. Is it more common to say "wait until it's less cold" or "wait until it's warmer" or "wait until it warms up"?

Tags: phrase-usage, phrases

You took a bottle of orange juice out of a fridge and put it on a table but you didn't want to drink it right then because it's still very cold. You wanted to leave it there for awhile.

Is it more common to say "**Please wait until it's less cold**" or "**Please wait until it's warmer**" or "**Please wait until it warms up**"?

Chatgpt suggests "Please wait until it warms up" is the best because it implies the temperature of the juice gradually increased.

Chatgpt also says "Please wait until it's less cold" is awkward though it is not wrong and "Please wait until it's warmer" is wrong.

Comment: I commend your wisdom in not trusting ChatGPT fully, and checking with actual humans!  ChatGPT is often mostly right, but it's also wrong just enough to get you into trouble (even before it starts hallucinating).  It's a good tool, but as I'm sure you're already aware, you need to be careful and understand it is quite fallable.

Comment: @RichardWinters - fallible.

Comment: Sorry for the typo.  I should know better as an English teacher!

Comment: They mean different things. Are you waiting for it to reach room temperature, nearly room temperature, or just slightly warmer than the fridge?

Comment: @StuartF, I want it to be not too cold or equal to the room's temperature so that I can drink

Answer (score 3):

Waiting until it "warms up" suggests it should actually get a little warm, as does "until it's warmer".  Both could be modified to tone this down: "... until it warms up a bit", or "... until it's a little warmer".

"Less cold" conveys that you still want it cold, just not as cold as when it first came out of the fridge.  It's not wrong, but perhaps a little unnatural in my British English, in this context and plenty of others.

An alternative I'd use when I want it to be pleasantly cold is to say "I'll wait until it's not (quite) so cold".

Answer (score 2):

They are all fine, I'd agree with Chatgpt that "warm up" is the best, and "until it is less cold" is rather awkward, but not wrong. But "until it is warmer" is also not wrong".

"Warm" and "warmer" is always relative to some implied standard. So compared to the temperature of the fridge, room temperature is "warm".